# Не получается подключить microSD card

Tags: arduino, esp32, sd, arduino-ide

Помогите, не получается подключить microSD card не к Arduino не к ESP32
нужно подключить к ESP32 , на Arduino просто тестировал работает ли вообще

Обарудование: ESP32 devkit v1 , Arduino nano , MicroSD Card Adapter , MicroSD card SanDisk
64gb eXFat

Софт: Arduino IDE , Библиотека SdFat (version:2.2.2) , Скетч это пример из библиотеки sdfat - (sdinfo)

Подключение к pins:
Adpter pin - CS , SCK , MOSI , MISO , VCC , GND
Arduino к Adapter - (CS , D10) (SCK , D13) (MOSI , D11) (MISO , D12) (VCC , +5V) (GND , GND)
ESP32 к Adapter - (CS , D27) (SCK , D14) (MOSI , D12) (MISO , D13) (VCC , VIN) (GND , GND)

Вывод ESP32:

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:8896
load:0x40080400,len:5828
entry 0x400806ac
```

Вывод Arduino:

```
SdFat version: 2.2.2

Assuming the SD is the only SPI device.
Edit DISABLE_CS_PIN to disable an SPI device.

Assuming the SD chip select pin is: 10
Edit SD_CS_PIN to change the SD chip select pin.

type any character to start
```

*это полные выводы из монитора порта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выяснил, что не так:

1. Общее для подключения к любому железу

   SdFat не работает именно у меня, так и не понял что не так с это библиотекой.
   так что лучше использовать стандартную библиотеку SD
2. Общее для подключения к любому железу

   Sd card(No name, SDHC, 32gb)

   Форматирование Sd card для библиотеки SD (возможно и для SdFat) должно быть в Fat32 c таблицей разделов msdos.

   ответ нашёл [тут](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/yet-another-sd-initialization-fail/286017).

   из-за неправильной таблицы разделов не читало мою карту.
3. ESP32 pin connect

   ESP32 к MicroSD Adapter - (CS , D5) (SCK , D18) (MOSI , D23) (MISO , D19) (VCC , VIN) (GND , GND)
4. Arduino pin connect

   Arduino к MicroSD Adapter - (CS , D4) (SCK , D13) (MOSI , D11) (MISO , D12) (VCC , +5V) (GND , GND)